# proj4js: converting EPSG:3857 to SWEREF99 TM

Tags: openstreetmap, convert, proj, browser, proj4js

I'm trying to convert a EPSG:3857(Google/OSM) coordinate to a SWEREF99 TM coordinate using proj4js but the following code produces a invalid result:

```
sweref99 = "+proj=utm +zone=33 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs "
proj4('EPSG:3857', sweref99, [17.375, 62.15])
```

Output: `[-1188634.4915465375, 63.90148326237714]`.
Expected output: `[623764.06663, 6893158.947579]`.

How can I solve this and convert a EPSG:3857 point to a SWEREF99 TM point?

Comment: You're passing in lat/lon coordinates (I assume) so your input CRS should be 'EPSG:4326' instead.

Comment: Closing as obsolete, unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The coordinates you're passing in are latitude and longitude values so the input coordinate reference system (CRS) should be 'EPSG:4326' or some other geographic CRS instead.